# How to clear the activity state when it goes in a background?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin

I have a scenario in which I have to move to app settings screen from my current app activity. There is a dialog that does this. When I put the dialog open and goes to settings screen explicitly and change something, the button of the dialog that has to take me to app settings does not work. Any help please ?

Comment: I am adding the intent to start activity in onCreate

Comment: can you explain more? as I understand that the button not redirecting you to the settings screen and keeps you on the same screen, can you share your code

Comment: @tamtom Yes you understand that correct. How to resolve this ?

Comment: Can you show the code pls?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the history, can you try:

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`